# Express webapp how to store/access user settings

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im currently developing a Nodejs/Express webapp similar to a dashboard/webbrowser homepage. The data is shown according to the user's settings. At the moment, I'm creating a json file (based on a template) when the user signs-up. This json file has the settings I need to access in order to show the information on the main page. Some of this information is: geolocation (city + country) to access a weather api (+ units, forecast days lenght, etc), a list of tvshows (so I can fetch a list of episodes from my db), etc.

At the moment, when a user logs-in, I'm reading this file about 4 times. I'm sure this is not a good idea, and although its working fine now, I can see the problems I'm going to have in the future (when I add more settings and/or get more traffic).

Since the webapp is almost done, I want to take care of this. I'm thinking on a couple of options:

1. Save the user settings in a session store (Redis e.g.)
2. Save the user settings in a cookie(s)
3. Read the file once when the user logs in, and cache it somehow

What's the best option to do this ?

Comment: why not storing in db?

Comment: When I was researching how to store user settings and the best approaches, I got to the conclusion that there's no right answer. There are some ways of storing user settings in relational databases (im using Postgres) but I would end up making a lot of tables+relations and lengthy queries. The other solution was to store the information on JSON files. I went for the last one, since it seemd easier/better. Am I missing something ? Do you thing I should switch to storing in a db ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to store this information client-side (since you've mentioned cookies), you might [consider looking into JavaScript's `localStorage` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) (or `sessionStorage` if you want the data to expire when the user closes his/her browser).

`localStorage` is a key:value pair (like you'd get with Redis), but the data is stored locally on the user's device. As with any client-side storage solutions, you should never trust the data provided from `localStorage` without some verification, but it's a tool designed exactly for this kind of task.

Comment: I'm not really sure whether to store client-side or server-side. I'm still debating that question. Anyways, thanks for the input, I'll take a look at localStorage.

Comment: From what I can tell, I can't access the localStorage API server-side. At least not directly. I'd have to make ajax requests to send the data to the server. Also, I don't really see any big differences between cookies and localStorage, so I'd probably use cookies instead.